# How to not run a Promise before I ask to

Tags: node.js, es6-promise

I thought I had it all figured out regarding Promise, but this one actually throws me out of bed. When creating a new Promise with a executor taking two arguments, why is this method running before I either take then() or catch() at that promise

Running node 6.2.2.

```
import assert = require('assert');

describe("When working with promises", () => {
    let ar = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];

    beforeEach(() => {

    })

    it("should be perfectly fine but isn't when mapping to promises", (done) => {
        ar.map(num => {
            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                done(new Error('Why on earth is ' + num + ' called'));
            })
        })

        done();
    })

    it("should be perfectly fine when mapping to methods", (done) => {

        ar.map(num => {
            return (resolve, reject) => {
                done(new Error(num + ' is not called ever'));
            }
        })

        done();
    })
});
```

First test fails, and second test is successful.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you check the [documentation for Promise](https://www.promisejs.org/), you will find that the function that is given to the constructor is run *immediately*. It is supposed to kick off the asynchronous calculation and install the two callbacks there (so that `resolve` and `reject` are not invoked just now, but whenever that calculation completes or fails).

The `Promise` function is *not* the asynchronous calculation, it just wraps that calculation and the two callbacks you need to keep track of it together into a nice package (and returns immediately after this setup is done).

Your second example creates an anonymous function for each number, but does not invoke any of them.

> why is this method running before I either take then() or catch() at that promise

The Promise does not care if you install any handlers/chains. The calculation will have been started (or not) no matter if anyone is watching it or not.

Comment: Thanks, I always thought I could run a Promise constructor multiple times. I can, but all work done in the executor will only run once

Answer (score 1):

To achieve the same behavior you have to wrap promises in a factory. You can use a lambda functions for that.

```
 it("should be perfectly fine but isn't when mapping to promises", (done) => {
     ar.map(num => {
         return () => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
             done(new Error('Why on earth is ' + num + ' called'));
         })
     })

     done();
 })
```

So you have stateless factories to call later without creating promises (that run **immediately**) during map.

It permits you to [compose and join Promises](http://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_promises.html#_composing-promises) for later batch execution using [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all), [Promise.race](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/race), or custom chaining.

Answer (score 1):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise:

> [...] The executor function is executed immediately by the Promise implementation, passing resolve and reject functions [...].

That's the way, the Promise implementation works. You can also create a new promise and attach chained `then()` or `catch()` handlers later when the promise already succeeded or failed.

```
const p = new Promise(someExecutor);
// do some other things
p.then(someHandler);
// do some other things
p.catch(someOtherHandler);
```

If you do not want the executor to execute, yet, then don't pass it to the `Promise` constructur, yet.

Answer (score 0):

If you want something to run only (i.e. not before) a "then()" handler is attached, then you can use plain then-ables ( https://promisesaplus.com/ )

```
var runLater = { 
  then: function(resolve, reject) { 
    var p = new Promise (...); // Creating a promise is optional
    resolve(p);  // you can return a plain value
  }
}
```

Note this is not a Promise, so it does not have a "catch" method.

But it can be given to any function expecting a promise:

- `Promise.all([runLater])
- return as result from a then handled `.then(function() { return runLater; })`
- `Promise.resolve(runLater)` => Now it is a promise with then/catch

Any of those will call the runLater.then method.